# How to set property of type function in jquery control using JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, custom-controls

I have one jquery datepicker control. Using which I want to create one custom ASP.net control.
JQuery datepicker has one property beforeShow. This property is of type function.
In ASP.Net cotrol, I am trying to set the function using string type by JSonItem as follows:

```
StringBuilder strFunction = new StringBuilder();
            strFunction.AppendLine(@"function (input) { ");
            strFunction.AppendLine(@" setTimeout(function () { ");
            strFunction.Append(@" var buttonPane = $(""#" + ClientID);
            strFunction.Append(@""")");
            strFunction.AppendLine(@".datepicker(""widget"").find("".ui-datepicker-close"").click(function () {");
            strFunction.Append(@" $.datepicker.clearDate($(""#" + ClientID );
            strFunction.AppendLine(@"""));");
            strFunction.AppendLine(@" });");
            strFunction.AppendLine(@" }, 1);");
            strFunction.AppendLine("}"); 

textInput.Call("datepicker", Js.Json(
                Js.JsonItem("onSelect", Js.Function(delegate {
                    if (ValueSelected != null) {
                        var request = CreateMethodInvocationRequest("OnSelect");
                        request.Send();
                    }
                })
            ),
//This is the function type of property

Js.JsonItem("beforeShow",strFunction.ToString())



));
```

Here but I am not getting the result. Runtime JScript error is getting thrown.If I don't set beforeShow property then everything works fine. But I need this property. Can anyone suggest other approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using one function which returns parses the string into JSExpression.

```
Js.JsonItem("beforeShow",strFunction.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

User the one from the following as per your need instead of beforeShow,

**render,
beforerender,
afterrender**

we cant use beforeShow, because it is triggered only when it is used with the show method..

Comment: Hi Vinoth Babu, it is not the problem with beforeShow property. It is the problem with strFunction.ToString(). We can't pass the function as string.That's my question. How to pass function?